# Armory scan hangs each time on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: armory

I installed Armory 0.96 (armory_0.96-gcc5.4_amd64.deb) on Ubuntu 16.04. It worked for me a couple of times but now it seems to get stuck on the scan part.

After I close Armory I cannot start it again. The log shows something like

```
Log file opened at 1498017814: /home/ubuntu/.armory/armorycpplog.txt

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 06:03 (ERROR) -- ArmoryQt.py:5906 - Socket already in use.  Sent CLI args to existing proc.
2017-06-21 06:03 (ERROR) -- ArmoryQt.py:5907 - Exiting...
```

Armory looks looks very good, looks like a lot of hard work went into creating it, so I am a bit surprised at this result. It looks like there are still major issues with it.

Should I switch to other OS? MS Windows? It does not look like this runs reliably on Ubuntu.

On first start - when scan seems to hang - logs are as follows

```
ubuntu:~] $ sudo tail -f .armory/armorylog.txt .armory/armorycpplog.txt .armory/dbLog.txt /var/log/syslog
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3590 - Using settings file: /home/ubuntu/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
2017-06-21 05:49 (ERROR) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3747 - Unsupported language  specified. Defaulting to English (en)
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3750 - Using Language: en
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- BDM.py:368 - Using the asynchronous/multi-threaded BlockDataManager.
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- BDM.py:369 - Blockchain operations will happen in the background.  
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- BDM.py:370 - Devs: check TheBDM.getState() before asking for data.
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- BDM.py:371 - Registering addresses during rescans will queue them for 
2017-06-21 05:49 (INFO) -- BDM.py:372 - inclusion after the current scan is completed.
2017-06-21 05:49 (ERROR) -- ArmoryQt.py:5906 - Socket already in use.  Sent CLI args to existing proc.
2017-06-21 05:49 (ERROR) -- ArmoryQt.py:5907 - Exiting...

==> .armory/armorycpplog.txt <==


Log file opened at 1497968678: /home/ubuntu/.armory/armorycpplog.txt
-ERROR - 1497968679: (SwigClient.cpp:61) can't connect socket


Log file opened at 1498016894: /home/ubuntu/.armory/armorycpplog.txt


Log file opened at 1498016990: /home/ubuntu/.armory/armorycpplog.txt

==> .armory/dbLog.txt <==
-INFO  - 1498016004: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:650) scanned from height #472200 to #472200
-INFO  - 1498016353: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:650) scanned from height #472201 to #472201
-INFO  - 1498016685: (nodeRPC.cpp:368) Bitcoin server stopping
-INFO  - 1498016686: (SocketObject.cpp:350) POLLIN recv return 0
-ERROR - 1498016686: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:1037) caught StopBlockingLoop in processDataStackThread
-INFO  - 1498016686: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:969) Disconnected from Bitcoin node
-INFO  - 1498016704: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:947) Connected to Bitcoin node
-INFO  - 1498016727: (SocketObject.cpp:350) POLLIN recv return 0
-ERROR - 1498016727: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:1037) caught StopBlockingLoop in processDataStackThread
-INFO  - 1498016727: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:969) Disconnected from Bitcoin node

==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jun 21 05:54:15 io org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2363]: (nautilus:2789): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Jun 21 05:54:15 io org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2363]: (nautilus:2789): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Jun 21 05:54:15 io nautilus: [N-A] Nautilus-Actions Tracker 3.2.3 initializing...
Jun 21 05:54:15 io org.freedesktop.fwupd[884]: (fwupd:2781): Fu-WARNING **: Failed to coldplug: UEFI firmware updating not supported
Jun 21 05:54:15 io dbus[884]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Jun 21 05:54:17 io thermald[960]: sysfs write failed trip_point_0_temp
Jun 21 05:54:21 io thermald[960]: sysfs write failed trip_point_0_temp
Jun 21 05:54:25 io systemd-timesyncd[734]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun 21 05:54:33 io pulseaudio[2604]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Jun 21 05:54:34 io org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[2363]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:3133): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Jun 21 05:54:52 io systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Jun 21 05:54:52 io systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Jun 21 05:54:52 io systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1138 - C++ block utilities loaded successfully
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: free -m
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: ['cat', '/proc/cpuinfo']
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1255 - 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1256 - 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1257 - 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1258 - ************************************************************
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1259 - Invoked: /usr/local/bin/../lib/armory/ArmoryQt.py
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1260 - ************************************************************
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1261 - Loading Armory Engine:
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1262 -    Armory Version        : 0.96
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1263 -    Armory Build:         : a3d01aa722
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1264 -    PyBtcWallet  Version  : 1.35
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1265 - Detected Operating system: Linux
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1266 -    OS Variant            : Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1267 -    User home-directory   : /home/ubuntu
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1268 -    Satoshi BTC directory : /home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1269 -    Armory home dir       : /home/ubuntu/.armory/
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1270 - Detected System Specs    : 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1271 -    Total Available RAM   : 15.58 GB
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1272 -    CPU ID string         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1273 -    Number of CPU cores   : 8 cores
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1274 -    System is 64-bit      : True
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1275 -    Preferred Encoding    : UTF-8
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1276 -    Machine Arch          : x86_64
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1277 -    Available HDD (ARM)   : 25 GB
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1278 -    Available HDD (BTC)   : 25 GB
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1279 - 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1280 - Network Name: Main Network
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1281 - Satoshi Port: 8333
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1282 - Do wlt check: True
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1283 - Named options/arguments to armoryengine.py:
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     thread_count    : -1
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     rescan          : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     ignoreAllZC     : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     rescanBalance   : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     disableModules  : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     port            : None
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     interport       : 8223
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     coverageOutputDir: None
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     forceWalletCheck: False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     regtest         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     rebuild         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     nettimeout      : 2
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     datadir         : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     clearMempool    : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     offline         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     armoryDBDir     : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     armorydb_port   : 9001
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     satoshiPort     : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     useTorSettings  : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     netlog          : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     keypool         : 100
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     coverageInclude : None
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     forceOnline     : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     redownload      : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     rpcBindAddr     : 127.0.0.1
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     armorydb_ip     : 127.0.0.1
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     multisigFile    : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     ram_usage       : -1
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     mtdebug         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     logDisable      : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     settingsPath    : /home/ubuntu/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     language        : en
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     db_type         : DB_FULL
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     doDebug         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     enableDetSign   : True
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     disableConfPermis: False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     testnet         : False
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     rpcport         : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     satoshiHome     : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     satoshiRpcport  : DEFAULT
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     logFile         : /home/ubuntu/.armory/ArmoryQt.py.log.txt
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1285 -     verbosity       : None
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1286 - Other arguments:
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1289 - ************************************************************
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:1692 - C++ block utilities loaded successfully
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3590 - Using settings file: /home/ubuntu/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
2017-06-21 05:55 (ERROR) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3747 - Unsupported language  specified. Defaulting to English (en)
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3750 - Using Language: en
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- BDM.py:368 - Using the asynchronous/multi-threaded BlockDataManager.
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- BDM.py:369 - Blockchain operations will happen in the background.  
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- BDM.py:370 - Devs: check TheBDM.getState() before asking for data.
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- BDM.py:371 - Registering addresses during rescans will queue them for 
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- BDM.py:372 - inclusion after the current scan is completed.

==> .armory/armorycpplog.txt <==


Log file opened at 1498017359: /home/ubuntu/.armory/armorycpplog.txt

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:3590 - Using settings file: /home/ubuntu/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:2042 - loadWalletsAndSettings
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:2102 - Loading wallets...
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:2167 - Number of wallets read in: 1
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:2172 -    Wallet (SG4vvFdh):    "OU Sparen (Watch)               "   (No Encryption)
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1747 - acquiring process mutex...
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1385 - setupUriRegistration
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/bitcoin/command
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/bitcoin
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:558 - Usermode: Advanced
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1681 - Changing usermode:
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1682 -    From: Advanced
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1690 -      To: Advanced
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1814 - startBitcoindIfNecessary
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1850 - setSatoshiPaths
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1868 - Setting satoshi datadir = /opt/blockchains/bitcoin
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: ['whereis', 'bitcoind']
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:289 - "whereis" returned: ['/usr/bin/bitcoind']
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:169 - Found bitcoind in the following places:
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:171 -    /usr/bin/bitcoind
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:171 -    /usr/bin/bitcoind
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:173 - Using: /usr/bin/bitcoind
2017-06-21 05:55 (INFO) -- SDM.py:337 - Called startBitcoind
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: ['/usr/bin/bitcoind', u'-datadir=/opt/blockchains/bitcoin']
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- SDM.py:443 - PID of bitcoind: 3379
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- SDM.py:444 - PID of armory:   3345
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: ['python', '/usr/local/lib/armory/guardian.py', '3345', '3379']
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1850 - setSatoshiPaths
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1868 - Setting satoshi datadir = /opt/blockchains/bitcoin
2017-06-21 05:56 (WARNING) -- SDM.py:396 - Spawning DB with command:ArmoryDB --db-type="DB_FULL" --cookie --satoshi-datadir="/opt/blockchains/bitcoin/blocks" --datadir="/home/ubuntu/.armory/" --dbdir="/home/ubuntu/.armory/databases"
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryUtils.py:665 - Executing popen: ['ArmoryDB', '--db-type="DB_FULL"', '--cookie', u'--satoshi-datadir="/opt/blockchains/bitcoin/blocks"', '--datadir="/home/ubuntu/.armory/"', '--dbdir="/home/ubuntu/.armory/databases"']

==> .armory/dbLog.txt <==


Log file opened at 1498017360: /home/ubuntu/.armory/dbLog.txt
-INFO  - 1498017360: (main.cpp:23) Running on 8 threads
-INFO  - 1498017360: (main.cpp:24) Ram usage level: 4
-INFO  - 1498017360: (BlockUtils.cpp:907) blkfile dir: /opt/blockchains/bitcoin/blocks
-INFO  - 1498017360: (BlockUtils.cpp:908) lmdb dir: /home/ubuntu/.armory/databases
-INFO  - 1498017360: (lmdb_wrapper.cpp:388) Opening databases...

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1900 - Setting netmode: 1

==> .armory/armorycpplog.txt <==
-ERROR - 1498017360: (SwigClient.cpp:61) can't connect socket

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1900 - Setting netmode: 0
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:1882 - loadBlockchainIfNecessary
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:4619 - Dashboard switched to "Scanning" mode

==> .armory/dbLog.txt <==
-INFO  - 1498017360: (BlockUtils.cpp:1091) Executing: doInitialSyncOnLoad

==> .armory/armorylog.txt <==
2017-06-21 05:56 (INFO) -- ArmoryQt.py:4619 - Dashboard switched to "Scanning" mode

==> .armory/dbLog.txt <==
-INFO  - 1498017360: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:169) Reading headers from db
-INFO  - 1498017363: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:208) Found 472202 headers in db
-INFO  - 1498017364: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:51) updating HEADERS db
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:477) Found next block after skipping 356528bytes
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:268) parsed block file #910
-DEBUG - 1498017365: (Blockchain.cpp:242) Organizing chain 
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:56) updated HEADERS db in 0.348001s
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:106) scanning new blocks from #472202 to #472201
-INFO  - 1498017365: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:52) no history to scan
-INFO  - 1498017365: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:813) no SSH to scan
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:156) scanned new blocks in 0.000506s
-INFO  - 1498017365: (DatabaseBuilder.cpp:160) init db in 3.77501s
-INFO  - 1498017365: (BlockUtils.cpp:1206) Enabling zero-conf tracking 

==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Stopped target Default.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Stopped target Timers.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Stopped target Paths.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[2017]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 3413 (kill).
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Jun 21 05:56:08 io systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.

==> .armory/dbLog.txt <==
-INFO  - 1498017395: (BitcoinP2P.cpp:947) Connected to Bitcoin node
-INFO  - 1498017395: (nodeRPC.cpp:59) RPC connection established
-INFO  - 1498017431: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:650) scanned from height #472202 to #472204
-INFO  - 1498017443: (BlockchainScanner.cpp:650) scanned from height #472205 to #472205
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 10 zc parser threads
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 15 zc parser threads
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 20 zc parser threads
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 25 zc parser threads
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 30 zc parser threads
-WARN  - 1498017443: (BDM_supportClasses.cpp:1891) running 35 zc parser threads

==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jun 21 05:58:10 io thermald[960]: sysfs write failed trip_point_0_temp
```

Comment: The logged error ```Socket already in use``` seems to indicate that there is already an instance of Armory running - or another application is perhaps using port 8223?

Comment: Don't think that is it. It is just user interface stuff https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/ArmoryQt.py#L5906

Comment: At the cmd line, try ```netstat -al | grep 8223```. If anything shows up then there is an app using that port. Also: ```ps -ef | grep -i armor``` (or whatever the Armory process is called), and try to see if ```bitcoind``` is perhaps running in the background. Seems like when you previously exited Armory, its process was not killed...

Comment: I removed armory and .armory directory and installed again, now it is working again. I keep the blockchain in separate directory / NFS share so this was a good enough solution for now.

Comment: If you're using an NFS for blockchain storage this implies you're getting intermittent read/write locks that can cause Armory to hang and not properly terminate via user shutdown. Recommend you run ```bitcoind``` with local storage for datadir.

Comment: That fixes the problem. Using a NFS share does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

This error means that the background database process, ArmoryDB, is still running. Just use `sudo killall -9 ArmoryDB` to kill all instances of this process and start Armory again. It's fine to use `-9` as ArmoryDB is good enough to handle a SIGKILL signal; I have done this many times myself.